# Mongoose SUM get stacked

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I'm trying to make trivial SUM on mongoDB to count number of prices for single client.

**My collection:**

```
{"_id":"5d973c71dd93adfbda4c7272","name":"Faktura2019006","clientId":"5d9c87a6b9676069c8b5e15b","expiration":"2019-10-02T01:11:18.965Z","price":999999,"userId":"123"},
{"_id":"5d9e07e0b9676069c8b5e15d","name":"Faktura2019007","clientId":"5d9c87a6b9676069c8b5e15b","expiration":"2019-10-02T01:11:18.965Z","price":888,"userId":"123"}
```

**What I tried:**

```
// invoice.model.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const InvoiceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String,
  name: String,
  client: String,
  userId: String,
  expiration: Date,
  price: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Invoice", InvoiceSchema, "invoice");
```

and

```
// invoice.controller.js
const Invoice = require("../models/invoice.model.js");

exports.income = (req, res) => {
  console.log("Counting Income");

  Invoice.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        userId: "123"
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        total: { $sum: ["$price"] }
      }
    }
  ]);
};
```

**What happen:**

When I now open a browser and code above is being called, I get console log 'Counting Income' in terminal however in browser it's just loading forever and nothing happen.

Most likely I just miss some stupid minor thing but I'm trying to find it out for quite a long time without any success so any advise is welcome.

Comment: You are not returning anything from the controller (sending the res from controller), that's why api is not returning anything at all

Comment: It's not about not returning, it keep loading :) So my problem is not I don't get response, problem is that fetch never ends

Comment: change group to {$group:{_id:null,total:{$sum:"$price"}}} and then try

Comment: @sushantmehta nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the controller never finishes is because you are not ending the response process (meaning, you need to use the `res` object and send something back to the caller).

In order to get the aggregate value, you also need to execute the pipeline (see [this example](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate)).

Also, as someone pointed out in the comments, you need to add `_id: null` in your group to specify that you are not going to group by any specific field (see the [second example here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#examples)).

Finally, in the `$sum` operator, for what you're trying to do, you just need to remove the array brackets since you only want to sum on a single field (see [a few examples down here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#examples)).

Here is the modified code:

```
// invoice.controller.js
const Invoice = require("../models/invoice.model.js");

exports.income = (req, res) => {
  console.log("Counting Income");

  Invoice.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        userId: "123"
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        total: { $sum: "$price" }
      }
    }
  ]).then((response) => {
    res.json(response);
  });
};
```

*Edit for your comment about when an empty array is returned.*

If you want to always return the same type of object, I would control that in the controller. I'm not sure if there is a fancy way to do this with the aggregate pipeline in mongo, but this is what I would do.

```
 Invoice.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        userId: "123"
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        total: { $sum: "$price" }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        total: "$total"
      }
    }
  ]).then((response) => {
    if (response.length === 0) {
      res.json({ total: 0 });
    } else {
      // always return the first (and only) value
      res.json(response[0]);
    }
  });
```

Here, if you find a `userId` of `123`, then you would get this as the return:

```
{
    "total": 1000887
}
```

But if you change the `userId` to, say, `1123` which doesn't exist in your db, the result will be:

```
{
    "total": 0
}
```

This way, your client can always consume the same type of object.

Also, the reason I put the `$project` pipeline stage in there was to suppress the `_id` field (see [here for more info](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html#pipe._S_project)).

Comment: Thank you @Joseph, you were right. Can I ask one additional thing. Now if it don't  match anything it will return empty object. Can I change it to make it same object with total value 0?

Comment: @Andurit glad to help! Sure thing, check out the new edit in the answer. I hope this helps.